# How to forge this mysql request?

Tags: mysql, sql, where-clause

I need to forge a request sql which is called by a php page but I get stuck on the way to write it...

i want make a request called by script :

http://localhost/script.php?Societe=&Nom=rgegr&Ville=&....

I have a table named : client

[image]

and a another table named suivi
[image]

I want this
[image]

i have try this :

```
SELECT client_id,Societe,Nom,SUM(suivi.Suivi),COUNT(suivi.num_client) 

FROM client,suivi 

WHERE num_client IN (select client_id from client WHERE client_id LIKE '%$id%' and Societe LIKE '%$Societe%' and Nom LIKE '%$Nom%' and Ville LIKE '%$Ville%' and Adresse LIKE '%$Adresse%' and Departement LIKE '%$Departement%' and Site LIKE '%$Site%' and Tel LIKE '%$Tel%');
```

Can you give me some advice

Thanks

Comment: What do you get when you try your query?

Comment: When you say "forge", do you mean it in the "create" or "falsify" sense?

Comment: What else did you try to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? Are you probably looking for `GROUP BY`?

Comment: When I group by the answer that is not the one I expect:
client_id | Societe | Nom | SUM(suivi.Suivi) | COUNT(suivi.num_client)
34 | greger | bfd | 10 | 10

And when i say "forge" i want make a request who combine num_client in same line with sum suivi and count number of entry suivi

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it